# Measuring the current of a DC circuit

Tags: current, integrated-circuit

I'm creating a set of modules that can be daisy chained and hooked up to a master controller unit. I'd like to have a display on the master that shows the combined current draw of the modules in realtime.

Is there an IC that you can pass the circuit through and then query (through I2C for example) for the current load?

This is a 5V project and the current will be in the range of 0 to 2 amps at most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a small MCU such as a PIC or AVR with an ADC to measure the voltage across a suitable resistor, calculate the current, and transmit the value via I2C.

Comment: So essentially use something like a 1 ohm resistor and two analog pins of my AtMega32U4 to measure the voltage difference across it then perform conversion to current?

Comment: That should work.

Answer (score 2):

Any "battery monitor" IC could do this easily. They are PM-BUS which is an I2C derivative.

Comment: some examples and reference design please.